# Is it possible to un-sudo apps that have been run with sudo?

Tags: sudo

I heard that its not ok to run stuff always with sudo, because its same like running stuff as administrator on other os. Is it possible to revert it and un-sudo it so it dont have root access?

Comment: Can you give us a more concrete example of the problem?

Comment: You can always close the app and re-run it without sudo privileges.

Comment: Related: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Comment: What happens if you just run the command without `sudo` ? Commands don't remember that they been run with sudo earlier.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to revert anything.

If you run a command prepending `sudo`, you'll run the command with root privileges.

If you run a command without sudo, you'll run the command with your user privileges.

Example:

```
$ sudo ls -a /root
[sudo] password for mook: 
.  ..  .bash_history  .bashrc  .cache  .local  .profile  .synaptic
~$ ls -a /root
ls: cannot open directory '/root': Permission denied
```

In this example I use the command `ls -a /root`, first with `sudo`, then without `sudo`. As you can see, in the second command I don't have root-access and get a `permission denied`, even if I have used the same command with sudo before.

Comment: Some apps/programs/commands need sudo to run well.  Should not use sudo to open programs that do not need it, like firefox.  Sudo apps should only run for short periods of time and be ended, sudo also usually has a set time before needing to be given again, you give a command with sudo and do not use another command within a few minutes, will need password again.

Comment: @crip659 `sudo also usually has a set time before needing to be given again` No, the time (usually15 min) is the time you don't need to enter the password when using sudo again within that time. Running a command without `sudo` will never evaluate privileges.

Comment: @mook765 "will never evaluate privileges" in the last comment should be "will never **elevate** privileges"

Comment: @karel Yes, sure.